# Re-binning Datasets Using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table

I have two datasets that contain tree canopy mortality classifications for aerial photographs. These two datasets were completed about 10 years apart, and therefore have different classification schema. Since consumers of these datasets will want to do comparisons of the datasets, I'd like to re-bin these classification data into a 'crosswalk' of sorts, where the severity of mortality is uniform for both surveys. I'm wondering how I might use ArcPy to accomplish this.

[image: 2009 classification schema]

[image: 2019 classification schema]

(Above) 2009 system of rating mortality

(Below) 2019 system of rating mortality

I would like to create a crosswalk for these two datasets so I can bin them using a schema common to both of them for comparison's sake.

Comment: I suspect ArcPy cursors are what you need to look at.